# Using queryset manager with prefetch_related

Tags: django

I have been succesfully using this brilliant technique to keep my code DRY encapsulating ORM relations in querysets so that code in views is simple and not containing foreign key dependency. But this time I face the following issue best descriped by code:

View:

```
vendors_qs = vendors_qs.select_related().prefetch_related('agreement_vendors')
```

Model
class AgreementVendorsQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

```
def some_filter1(self, option):
    result = self.filter(.....)
    return result

def some_filter2(self, option):
    result = self.filter(.....)
    return result
```

And a template:

```
{% for vendor in vendors_qs %}
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
           {% for vend_agr in vendor.agreement_vendors.all %}
               {{vend_agr.serial_number}}
           {% endfor %}
        <td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

The question is, how and where do I apply the `some_filter1` to vendor agreements given that it is fetched as `prefetch_related` relation. Do I have to apply the filter in the template somehow or in the view itself ? 
If I didn't put the question clearly enough, I will ask your questions to clarify further...

UPDATE:
Anna's asnwer looks very much like the truth, but one detail remains unclear. What if I want to apply several filters based on if-condition. For exapmle, if the filters were to apply to vendors, then the code would simply look like:

```
if (condition_1)
     vendors_qs = vendors_qs.filter1()
if (condition_2)
     vendors_qs = vendors_qs.filter2()
```

Comment: Answering update. You can apply all filters and after you are done with filtering you can apply prefetch

Comment: Sardorbek, could you please provide any code snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I clearly understand your question you need something like this

```
    vendors_qs = vendors_qs.prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('agreement_vendors', queryset=some_filter, to_attr='agreement_vendors_list'))
```

And then in template you can call it like `{% for vend_agr in vendor.agreement_vendors_list %}`

Comment: If I were you I would implement `VendorsQuerySet` with different methods for each conditionals and then check them (`condition_1`, `condition_2`) in for example `get_queryset` method in view and call appropriate method.

Comment: There should be your queryset from `some_filter1` method.

Comment: Anna, it looks like it should be queryset = AgreementVendors.objects.all().some_filter1